# Java can't find symbol compile error

Tags: compilation

I keep receiving the error when i compile cannot find symbol I have no idea why? Any help will    be  appreciated

```
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class numerical000 {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     int x = 0, a0 = 0, b0 = 4;
     int a1;
     int b1;
     int i;
     int myfunc = x-1;
     for (i=1 ; i<=2 ; i++ )
       x = ((a0+b0)/2);
       if ((f(a0)*f(x)) = 0) 
         System.out.println("The Root is"+x);
         if ((f(a0)*f(x)) > 0) {
           a1  = x;
           b1 = b0;
        }
        else {
          a1 = a0;
          b1 = x;
        }

      System.out.println("Root obtained: " + x);
      System.out.println("Estimated error: " + myfunc);
    }
 }
```

Comment: show the error so we can better help you

Answer (score 1):

Q: what's this supposed to be:

`for (i=1 ; i 0) {`

Q: why "else" block after a "for loop"???

These are the errors I get with your code snippet:

```
numerical000.java:10: ';' expected
    for (i=1 ; i 0) {
                ^
numerical000.java:10: not a statement
    for (i=1 ; i 0) {
                 ^
numerical000.java:13: 'else' without 'if'
    else {
    ^
3 errors
```

Q: Please post your exact code, and the exact error message :)

Comment: sorry guys my mistake source code edited now can you plz check the code again 
and ignore <pre><code>

Comment: Hi - thank you for the edits.  This is your current problem:  'f(a0)*f(x))` <= function "f()" isn't defined anywhere in your code!

Answer (score 1):

You have more to worry about here than compile errors.  It seems like you need to brush up on a few concepts first because logically your program won't do what you expect even if you did somehow get it to compile.

1. You are passing in arguments (string args[]) but you never retrieve them
2. else needs an if to match - not a for loop.   For is for iteration, if/else is for conditional logic.
3. as mentioned, for loop syntax needs fixing
4. you named a variable myfunc...for 'my function'?  That's a terrible name for a variable.

Please study each item above and revisit your program.  Then, walk through each line of code as if you were the computer executing the instructions.   Use paper to keep track of variables if you need to.  You'll start to see the issues you need to fix.

Post your findings if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((f(a0)*f(x)) = 0)
```

is an assignment, not a check.